# How to reduce the use of indices in my code when working with arrays?

Tags: python, indexing, indices

**Situation**:

I have been thinking many ways to set this board without index gymnastics. I have read the documentation already and I almost drowned. Any ideas on how to work with arrays in general without abusing indices? I am currently reading about `numpy`, `itertools` and some recipes in the Python Cookbook with some hope but any idea is welcomed.

```
# Set the x coordinates of Algebraic Chess Notation
files = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

# Name the squares on the board.
chessboard = [[x + str(y) for x in files] for y in range(1, 9, 1)]
 
# Here is the output
chessboard

[['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1', 'f1', 'g1', 'h1'],
 ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'f2', 'g2', 'h2'],
 ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3', 'e3', 'f3', 'g3', 'h3'],
 ['a4', 'b4', 'c4', 'd4', 'e4', 'f4', 'g4', 'h4'],
 ['a5', 'b5', 'c5', 'd5', 'e5', 'f5', 'g5', 'h5'],
 ['a6', 'b6', 'c6', 'd6', 'e6', 'f6', 'g6', 'h6'],
 ['a7', 'b7', 'c7', 'd7', 'e7', 'f7', 'g7', 'h7'],
 ['a8', 'b8', 'c8', 'd8', 'e8', 'f8', 'g8', 'h8']]
```

**What I am trying to do**:

I am setting up a function or method to set up the initial state of a chessboard as an example.

**What I thought**:

```
def initial_state():
    """ Set the traditional initial positions of the pieces in the chessboard."""
    # White staff file
    for index in range(7):
        if index == 0 or index == 7:
            chessboard[0][index] = 'Rw_'+ chessboard[0][index]
        elif index == 1 or index == 6:
            chessboard[0][index] = 'Nw_'+ chessboard[0][index]
        elif index == 2 or index == 5:
            chessboard[0][index] = 'Bw_'+ chessboard[0][index]
        elif index == 3:
            chessboard[0][index] = 'Qw_'+ chessboard[0][index]
        elif index == 4:
            chessboard[0][index] = 'Kw_'+ chessboard[0][index]

    # Black staff file
    for index in range(7):
        if index == 0 or index == 7:
            chessboard[7][index] = 'Rb_'+ chessboard[7][index]
        elif index == 1 or index == 6:
            chessboard[7][index] = 'Nb_'+ chessboard[7][index]
        elif index == 2 or index == 5:
            chessboard[7][index] = 'Bb_'+ chessboard[7][index]
        elif index == 3:
            chessboard[7][index] = 'Qb_'+ chessboard[7][index]
        elif index == 4:
            chessboard[7][index] = 'Kb_'+ chessboard[7][index]

    # Pawn white file
    chessboard[1] = ['pw_' + x for x in chessboard[1]]

    # Pawn black file
    chessboard[6] = ['pb_' + x for x in chessboard[6]]
```

Ugly... I know...

**Results of that**:

```
initial_state()

# That is the result of the last input
[['Rw_a1', 'Nw_b1', 'Bw_c1', 'Qw_d1', 'Kw_e1', 'Bw_f1', 'Nw_g1', 'h1'],
 ['pw_a2', 'pw_b2', 'pw_c2', 'pw_d2', 'pw_e2', 'pw_f2', 'pw_g2', 'pw_h2'],
 ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3', 'e3', 'f3', 'g3', 'h3'],
 ['a4', 'b4', 'c4', 'd4', 'e4', 'f4', 'g4', 'h4'],
 ['a5', 'b5', 'c5', 'd5', 'e5', 'f5', 'g5', 'h5'],
 ['a6', 'b6', 'c6', 'd6', 'e6', 'f6', 'g6', 'h6'],
 ['pb_a7', 'pb_b7', 'pb_c7', 'pb_d7', 'pb_e7', 'pb_f7', 'pb_g7', 'pb_h7'],
 ['Rb_a8', 'Nb_b8', 'Bb_c8', 'Qb_d8', 'Kb_e8', 'Bb_f8', 'Nb_g8', 'h8']]
```

**finally:**

Any ideas on how to work with arrays in general without abusing indices (in python 3.4.2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know an array sounds like a good representation of a chessboard, but why not use a dictionary?
you can have the positions as keys and the value as the piece:

```
chessboard = { "a1": "Rw", 
  "a2": "pw",
  "a3": "",
   ...
  "h7": "pb",
  "h8": ""}
```

You can call/set/update a position by key name using `chessboard['b2'] = "pw"`

this is much more powerful than arrays and indices... You don't necessarily need to fill the empty spaces until needed (but you should check that a space exists if you're going to call it by looking with `if 'b3' in chessboard.keys():`

Enjoy learning Python... it is a fun and powerful language!

Answer (score 1):

A general answer to your **BOLD** question: factor out common operations and make use of python's iterator functions, including `zip` and `enumerate`.  The following produces your original filled-in chessboard with many fewer lines.

```
files = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
chessboard = [[x + str(y) for x in files] for y in range(1, 9, 1)]
def board():
       print()
       for row in reversed(chessboard): print(row)
board()

for row, color in ((0, 'w'), (7, 'b')):
       for col, (label, piece) in enumerate(zip(chessboard[row],
              ('R', 'N', 'B', 'Q', 'K', 'B', 'N', 'R'))):
           chessboard[row][col] = piece + color + label
for row, color in ((1, 'w'), (6, 'b')):
       for col, label in enumerate(chessboard[row]):
           chessboard[row][col] = 'p' + color + label
board()
```

The following carries the factorization one step further.

```
for row, color in ((0, 'w'), (7, 'b'), (1, 'w'), (6, 'b')):
       for col, (label, piece) in enumerate(zip(chessboard[row],
              ('R', 'N', 'B', 'Q', 'K', 'B', 'N', 'R')
              if row in (0, 7) else ('p',)*8)):
           chessboard[row][col] = piece + color + label
```